# iTunes Store operation failed. The following URL schemes found in your app are disallowed: [fb]

Tags: ios, validation

Does anyone know why I am getting this error when I try to validate my app?  And/or how to fix it?  Nothing I've read says that you need to allow the scheme and twitter and instagram are working fine.

All of the url schemes I am using are declared in the app info.plist file.  When I build and run my app on my device all of the code works fine and when clicked my app will redirect to a specific facebook page.

Now I am attempting to validate my app so I am able to upload it to the app store.  When validating I get the error "iTunes Store operation failed. The following URL schemes found in your app are disallowed: [fb]"

If I remove the "fb" url scheme from my info.plist my app no longer redirects to the facebook app but it will open in safari (which I do not want) and it does validate.

How do I go about validating the "fb" url scheme so my app is able to validate and not get this error?

Here is a picture of my info.plist:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to declare `fb` as a custom URL scheme used by your app or as one your app needs to check with `canOpenURL`? You really need to provide more details. Please update your question. Do not post details in a comment.

Comment: You need to update your question with the relevant portion of your Info.plist file.

Comment: Updated to include the info.plist file ^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are declaring that your app's custom URL schemes are "instagram", "fbapi", "fb", etc.

Why? Your app should declare its own, unique, custom URL scheme if you want other apps to be able to launch your app.

If your actual intent is to list the schemes of other apps that your app needs to launch, then you are putting the list of schemes under the wrong key. You want to use the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key. There are plenty of examples for this. Please search on `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` for its proper use.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you so much for the help! I had no idea that even existed.

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't forget to accept answers that solve your questions. This lets people know that the question is solved (and it increases your rep).

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the (-) in your URL Types that exist in

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).